# Source in the Gemara about seven qualities of an individual's personality

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

I recently heard a Torah lesson in which the speaker mentioned that according to the Gemara there are seven different sections or aspects of a person:

1. How people view you
2. Your deepest emotional needs
3. How you think, learn and, communicate
4. How you behave in relationships
5. How you manifest anger
6. Your natural strengths/skills
7. Natural weaknesses, challenges, things you need to fix

Unfortunately, this speaker didn't mention *where* in the Gemara this is. I was wondering if anyone has any idea?

Perhaps, it would have been in the context of the sefiros or the days of the week?

I have no way to contact the person who gave over the lesson.

Comment: *"According to the Gemmorah"* - This looks like his personal classification and conclusions of various Talmudic sayings and discussions. See Mishnah Avot and more.

Comment: What’s his name, maybe somebody here can contact him?

Comment: Where does the gemara mention Sefirot?

Answer (score -1):

The Talmud ([Eruvin 65b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=65b&format=pdf)) says as follows:

> א"ר אילעאי בשלשה דברים אדם ניכר בכוסו ובכיסו ובכעסו ואמרי ליה אף
>   בשחקו
>
> R. Ila'i said: By three things may a person's character be determined:
>   By his cup, by his purse and by his anger; and some say: By his
>   laughter also. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Eiruvin.pdf))

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya NF. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. One of the key requirements is that this is a site for English questions and answers. Maybe you could translate your answer - you can always refer to sites like Sefaria (proper page [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.65b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: You should explain how this answers the question. Putting in the citation is not sufficient. Note that the question is about **seven** qualities found in a person, but this givesa three characteristics which show a person's basic character. The is different from the actual question.

Comment: I've added a translation to the Talmudic quote, in accordance with our [policy on Hebrew-only answers](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3437/how-should-we-handle-hebrew-only-answers?rq=1). You can improve the answer further by elaborating on how this passage addresses the question. Remember, you have up to 30,000 characters to express your point and you can always [edit] your post to add further details.